# Unable to send email, as per postfix fatal: unable to determine open file limit

Tags: java, email, java-8, macos-sierra, postfix-mta

I am using java to attempt to send an email.  This has worked in the recent past and no code with sending of emails has changed.  I am currently getting the following stack trace when I try to send an email from my code:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1984)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.someMachine.email.SmtpHandlerMailer.send(SmtpHandlerMailer.java:616)
    at com.someMachine.business.doSomething(InMyCode.java:648)
    at com.someMachine.resource.someEmailResource.sendEmail(someEmailResource.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:301)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)
    ... 54 more
```

I think I've narrowed it down to postfix not launching on my machine.  As recently as a few weeks ago sending mail in this way was just fine.

I have, starting in macOS 10.9, changed the launchctl plist configuration to have macOS keep postfix running.  Currently it appears to be failing to launch every 10 seconds with the following messages (via console):

```
default 09:17:49.283668 -0700   master  subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0

default 09:17:49.284396 -0700   master  fatal: unable to determine open file limit
```

Manually launching it gives me the following output:

```
> sudo postfix start                                                                                                 postfix: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
postfix: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
postfix: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: mail system startup failed
```

Frustratingly, there are no log files anywhere I can find to look at on why the process isn't actually starting.  Presumably it's a configuration issue of some sort, but I can't seem to find anything wrong or any way to change the settings to allow postfix to launch.

`/etc/postfix/master.cf` and `/etc/postfix/main.cf` config files are the default macOS ones.

I am using homebrew, and have considered the possibility of brew having installed something that broke postfix indirectly, but have had no success looking in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

> unable to determine open file limit

As suggested in this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7457455), the error could be related to incompatibility with your macOS kernel

> This appears to be because postfix calls `getrlimit` in a way that it incompatible with the macOS kernel
>   or system library API, perhaps involving comparison with `RLIM_INFINITY`.

I believe this should be reported as a bug to Apple support, so they can fix it on their side.

Check similar [bug in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=627026).